# If $\#(S)<\#(\Bbb N)$, then prove that $S$ is finite, without using the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, alternative-proof, axiom-of-choice

> If we have a set $S$ such that $\#(S)<\#(\Bbb N)$, where $\Bbb N$ is the set of the natural numbers, how would one prove that $S$ must be finite?

Here is a proof using the Axiom of Choice:

**Proof**: From $\#(S)<\#(\mathbb{N})$, we know that there exists an injection $f:S\to \mathbb{N}$. On the other hand, $S$ cannot be an infinite set: If $S$ is infinite, it contains a copy of $\mathbb{N}$ by the Axiom of choice. Therefore, we have an injection $g:\mathbb{N}\to S$. By the Schröder–Bernstein Theorem, $\#(S)=\#(\mathbb{N})$, which is a contradiction.

Can we prove the theorem without the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?

Comment: If $f\colon A\to B$ is an injection, then this means that there is a set $A'\subseteq B$ such that $f\colon A\to A'$ is a bijection. In particular, this means that if $\#A\leq\#\Bbb N$, then there is a subset $A'$ of $\Bbb N$ such that $\#A=\#A'$.

Therefore, it is enough to prove that if $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ then either $A$ is finite, or $\#A=\#\Bbb N$. The standard proof of this fact don't use the axiom of choice at all, since $\Bbb N$ is given with a standard well-ordering which is inherited by all of its subsets.

Comment: What exactly is "the standard proof of this fact"?

Comment: The standard proof is the one given by Hagen, essentially. If $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ is non-empty, define $g(0)=\min A$ and $g(n+1)=\min\{a\in A\mid a>g(n)\}$ if that set is non-empty, otherwise stop. This is a bijection between $A$ and either $\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$, or $\Bbb N$ itself.

Comment: @ArcticChar I think the "confusing proof" should be included. It is the natural proof; the fact that it doesn't use AoC is, I guess, the point of Asaf's comment (and is not obvious to those who do not think about AoC much). Also, without the additional proof the question is low quality and should be closed.

Comment: @user1729 To me that is pushing a bit too far (using Schröder–Bernstein to prove this). It's too fake as a trial. I went through this result in a first course in analysis, and I don't see how people would know Schroder-Bernstein but not the usual proof... (But of course I could be wrong). I've made an edit anyway.

Answer (score 14):

By definition of $<$ for cardinalities, there exists an  injection $f\colon S\to \Bbb N$. For $n\in\Bbb N$, let $$h(n)=\Big|\big\{\,x\in f(S)\mid x<n\,\big\}\Big|\,.$$ If $h$ is bounded, $h(n)<M$ for all $n$,  this shows that $f(s)<M$ for all $s\in S$, whence $f$ can be viewed as map $\to\{0,\ldots, M\}$ and $S$ is finite; on the other hand, if $h$ is not bounded, for $n\in\Bbb N$, let $$m=\min\big\{\,k\in\Bbb N\mid h(j)\ge n\,\big\}\,,$$ observe that then $m\in f(S)$, and define $g(n)=f^{-1}(m)$. This gives us an injection (in fact, bijection)  $\Bbb N\to S$.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming $$\# (S)<\#(\Bbb N)$$ we do not need choice, we just need to take the smallest element after the previous one, if it is finite it will end, if it is not finite than it will create bijective from $S$ to $\Bbb N$, and thus $\# (S)=\# (\Bbb N)$, this is contradiction thus $\# (S)<\#(\Bbb N)$ implies $S$ is finite.

**But** assuming $$\# (S)\not\ge\#(\Bbb N)$$is **not** enough to show $S$ is finite without choice! There exists [infinite finite-dedekind set which is not comparable to $\Bbb N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2800249/471959)! But if you assume the axiom us choice it is provable that those sets do not exists.

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between $\#(s)<\#(N)$ and $\#(s) \ngeq \#(N)$ and why this makes a difference between requiring the axiom of choice or not. Could you explain this some more?

Comment: @A.Smith $\# A<\# B$ if and only if there *exists* injective function from $A$ to $B$ but there is no bijective function from $A$ to $B$. $\# A\ngeq\# B$ if and only if there is *no* injective nor bijective from $B$ to $A$, apparently if we do not assume choice the two are not equivalent but assuming choice they are equivalent

Answer (score -1):

I think you can prove this by assuming that a set is infinite, you can clearly select an element and by definition of infinity you can select another element ad infinitum and you can enumerate the element that you selected at step as n.

Comment: That is *exactly* the proof that requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: "Selecting" without an explicit formula for how the selection is made means  using the Axiom of Choice.  The sentence $\forall  n\in \Bbb N\; \forall \{x_j: n>j\in \Bbb N\}\; \exists x_n\in S$ \ $\{x_j:n>j\in \Bbb N\}\;$ is not the same as  $\exists f:\Bbb N\to S\; \forall n\in \Bbb N\; (f(n)\not \in \{f(j):n>j\}).$